# insert an object to database with a controller and validator using Spring MVC 3

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, controller

I'm trying to insert objects type "User" to the database but i get this error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/pages/gestionUser.jsp at line 165

162:                        
163:                <tr> 
164:                    <td id="idtab">Nom :</td> 
165:                     <td><form:input type="text" path="nom" class="round default-width-input"/></td>
166:                     <td><form:errors path="nom" cssClass="errorbox" /></td>                        
167:                </tr>
168:                <tr>
```

the Exception is :
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute**

This is my form :

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajouter_user" method="post" commandName="user">

                    <table id="tabmenu">


                <tr> 
                    <td id="idtab">Nom :</td> 
                     <td><form:input type="text" path="nom" class="round default-width-input"/></td>
                     <td><form:errors path="nom" cssClass="errorbox" /></td>                        
                </tr>
                <tr>            
                 <td id="idtab">Prénom :</td>
                 <td> <form:input type="text" path="prenom" class="round default-width-input"/></td>
                 <td><form:errors path="prenom" cssClass="errorbox" /></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="idtab">Login :</td>
                <td> <form:input type="text" path="login" cssClass="round default-width-input"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="login" class="errorbox" /></td>  
                <tr>
                <td id="idtab">Password :</td>
                <td> <form:input type="password" path="password" class="round default-width-input"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="errorbox" /></td>    
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td id="idtab">Séléctionner un rôle :</td>
            <td> <form:select path="role">
                                <form:option value="" label="Selectionner" />
                                <form:option value="1">Administrateur</form:option>
                                <form:option value="2">Simple utilisateur</form:option>
                </form:select></td>
            <td><form:errors path="role" cssClass="errorbox" /></td>    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="idtab">Désactivé :</td> 
                <td><form:input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked" path="enable"/>  Oui</td>    
            </tr>
             <tr></tr>
             <tr></tr>
                         <tr> <td colspan=2><input class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow" type="submit" value="Créer"></td></tr>

                    </table>
                </form:form>
                    <div class="success"><c:out value="${msg_success}"  /></div>
                        </div> <!-- end content-module-main -->

                    </div> <!-- end content-module -->
```

this is the method in the controller which implements SimpleFormController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajouter_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(ModelMap model,Object command) {
        User user = (User) command;
        userservice.AddUser(user);
        String msg= "Vous avez ajouter un utilisateur avec succès !";
        model.addAttribute("msg_success",msg);
        return "gestionUser";

    }
```

Please Help ? Where is the mistake ? Thank you

---

this is my controller :

```
package gestion.delegation.controller;

import gestion.delegation.domaine.User;
import gestion.delegation.service.ImplIUserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;




@Controller
public class GestionUserController{

    private ImplIUserService userservice;

    @Autowired
    public void setImplserv(ImplIUserService userservice) {
        this.userservice = userservice;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajouter_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public String add(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        userservice.AddUser(user);
        String msg= "Vous avez ajouter un utilisateur avec succès !";
        model.addAttribute("msg_success",msg);
        return "gestionUser";

    }
}
```

this is the class User

```
    package gestion.delegation.domaine;

    public class User {
        int id;
        String nom;
        String prenom;
        String login;
        String password;
        String role;
        boolean enable;
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getNom() {
            return nom;
        }
        public void setNom(String nom) {
            this.nom = nom;
        }
        public String getPrenom() {
            return prenom;
        }
        public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
            this.prenom = prenom;
        }
        public String getLogin() {
            return login;
        }
        public void setLogin(String login) {
            this.login = login;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        public boolean getEnable() {
            return this.enable;
        }
        public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
            this.enable = enable;
        }

        public User(int id, String 

nom, String prenom, String login,
            String password, String role, boolean enable) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.enable = enable;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    public User() {
        super();
    }

}
```

The validator :

```
package gestion.delegation.validator;

import gestion.delegation.domaine.User;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class AddUserValidator implements Validator{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

        return User.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors err) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "nom", "name.required","Choisissez un nom");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "prenom", "prenom.required", "Choisissez un prenom");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "login", "login.required", "Choisissez un login");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "password", "password.required", "Choisissez un password");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(err, "role", "role.required", "Choisissez un role");

    }

}
```

this is the declaration of the validator and the controller package in Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <bean id="AddUserValidator" class="gestion.delegation.validator.AddUserValidator" />


     <context:component-scan base-package="gestion.delegation.controller" />
```

Comment: That controller does not have a requestmapping to render the form - it will just process the form post. It is the controller used to render the form which requires the method annotated with @ModelAttribute. Add that to the correct controller and you will be in business.

Comment: YES !! Now i can go to the form, but when I fill the fields or i leave it empty another error appears : 


**Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into utilisateurs (id,login, password, nom, prenom,enable) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)]; Column 'login' cannot be null; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'login' cannot be null**
I can check for my mistakes for mysql but the question is **why the validator is not working ?**

Comment: I suggest you post that as a separate question - there's too much irrelevant stuff on this one now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I am going to assume that you do have a user in your model. So in order to post it back into your controller you can use the same annotation and just make it one of the arguments in your method. When your form is submitted, Spring will bind it to the User argument:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajouter_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute User user ) {
        userservice.AddUser(user);
        String msg= "Vous avez ajouter un utilisateur avec succès !";
        model.addAttribute("msg_success",msg);
        return "gestionUser";

    }
```

Comment: Even I do that no results, it still not working, but i wonder if the Validator is the problem here? should I create two method ? one call the validator and the second call the ServiceManager to insert to the database? I declared the validator in the XML file . Thank you sir for answering

Comment: **Etat HTTP 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute** But doesn't show me the line

Comment: When does the error happen? When you view the page or when you post the form? Does the user get added to the database?

Comment: when I click on the link to show the page where  the form is. I can't view the form yet nor insert in the fields

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear. In which case the answer below about putting a user bean in to the model should have done the trick. You could try naming the model attribute explicitly @ModelAttribute("user"). also I noticed you are implementing SimpleFormController. This is no longer recommended - instead just use annotations to map requests to methods. If this doesn't help please post your controller code

Comment: ok look i want to add a user to database, so in the index page i put a link to a another page where i want to do all operations of the users : insert, uppdate and delete. now i just work in the form of inserting, so when i click in the link to view the form the exception appears

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a user bean into the model. The form requires it because of the commandName="user" attribute.

One way of doing this is with the [modelAttribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) annotation

Something like this

```
@ModelAttribute
public User user(){
    return new User();
}
```

Comment: I try it but it's not working ! I have now the same exception **Etat HTTP 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute** but without showing the error in the line 165